# Como posso transformar uma variável(0-10) em 3 categorias?

Tags: r

A variável GLEASON da base de dados está de 0 a 10. E eu queria transformar esta variável em 3 categorias, por exemplo: 0-4: pouco agressivo, 5-7: agressivo intermedio e 8-10: muito agressivo. Em programação R.
Obrigada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma simples e de fácil compreensão é utilizando os vetores lógicos de análise de dados. Os vetores geram valores TRUE/FALSE que validam a execução seguinte. Neste exemplo, os dados estão num `data.frame` e ao fazer a primeira verificação automaticamente criamos a variável `categoria`.

```
dados <- data.frame(GLEASON = sample(0:10, 50, replace = TRUE))

dados$categorias[dados$GLEASON <= 4] <- 'pouco agressivo'
dados$categorias[dados$GLEASON >= 5 & dados$GLEASON <= 7] <- 'agressivo intermedio'
dados$categorias[dados$GLEASON >= 8] <- 'muito agressivo'

head(dados)
 GLEASON           categorias
       9      muito agressivo
       1      pouco agressivo
       8      muito agressivo
      10      muito agressivo
      10      muito agressivo
       6 agressivo intermedio
```

Comment: Obrigada, eu tentei fazer "e" com "&" mas estava a fazer de maneira errada. :)

Answer (score 4):

Outra opção é usar a função `cut`. Utilizando o data.frame criado pelo @Daniel:

```
dados <- data.frame(GLEASON = sample(0:10, 50, replace = TRUE))
dados$categorias <- cut(dados$GLEASON, c(0,4,7,10),
   include.lowest = T, labels = c("pouco agressivo",
   "agressivo intermedio","muito agressivo"))
```

O primeiro argumento é o vetor numérico, o segundo é o vetor de cortes, o terceiro é para indicar se inclui o valor mais baixo, 0, e último são as categorias que você quer.

Comment: A vantagem aqui é que nesse o tipo da coluna `categorias` será  [*Factor*](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/classes/s133/factors.html) ao invés de `Character`. Factors são mais econômicos em termos de memória.

Comment: Você também pode adicionar o argumento ordered_result=TRUE para ordernar as categorias, dependendo da análise que quer fazer.